# SQL Regex String Matching of Two Words

Tags: sql-server, regex

I'm trying to write a query to show the rows containing a code that begins with 11-digit number followed by `-1` or `-2` then `_DataSheet` or `_RoHS`

**Examples**

```
02704198976-1_DataSheet
03448106681-1_RoHS
```

**Query**

```
SELECT m.PK, m.code
FROM medias m
WHERE m.code LIKE CONCAT(REPLICATE('[0-9]', 11),'-[1-2]_(DataSheet|RoHS)%')
```

**Results**

0 rows returned

If I change the `WHERE` clause, then it shows too may results.

**Query**

```
SELECT m.PK, m.code
FROM medias m
WHERE m.code LIKE CONCAT(REPLICATE('[0-9]', 11),'-[1-2]_%')
```

**Results**

```
02704198976-1_DataSheet
03448100857-1_SDS      
03448106681-1_RoHS
```

Comment: Is that `%` in the end required or not?

Comment: @yper-trollᵀᴹ Yes, since there may be characters after those words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without regex, I think you need an `OR` for the last requirement (for the part that is either `DataSheet` or `RoHS`:

```
WHERE m.code LIKE CONCAT(REPLICATE('[0-9]', 11), '-[1-2][_]DataSheet%')
   OR m.code LIKE CONCAT(REPLICATE('[0-9]', 11), '-[1-2][_]RoHS%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Per https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859(v=sql.110).aspx `LIKE` on sql server does not deal with `()` constructs as a regex would do, hence the failure of your first query.

This command is too simple for your problem, you need a true regex, which does not seem to exist for SQL Server natively.

You may rewrite your latest query adding:

```
AND (m.code LIKE '%_DataSheet' OR m.code LIKE '%_RoHS')
```

and it should do the job, even if not pretty, nor 100% correct (as you can't anchor the strings at the end), nor easy to extend in a sane way...